# Validation of an Azure AD Bearer Token in a Console Application

Tags: c#, azure, jwt, bearer-token, azure-active-directory

You can find tons of examples how to secure an ASP.Net Application with Azure AD using JWT Bearer Authentication. It is as easy as adding some Information about your AAD in your Startup, like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
    {
        Authority = "https://login.windows.net/...",
        Audience = "...",
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Nothing is wrong with those examples, all the Token-Validation-Magic happens behind the scenes and you don't have to take care about it. But actually I would like to know how to validate an Azure AD Bearer Token apart from ASP.Net, e.g. in a Console Application.

Within a Console Application, I would expect something like the following:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   string token = "...";

   JwtSecurityToken validatedJwtToken = validateJwtToken(token);
}

private static JwtSecurityToken validateJwtToken(string token)
{
    JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken(token)

    //
    // how to validate the AAD token?!
    //

    if(/* is valid */)
    {
        return jwtToken;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I did't found a working example yet, but I can't imagine there is no easy solution for this problem. Any advice is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution - based on https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation:

```
private const string AUDIENCE = "<GUID of your Audience>";
private const string TENANT = "<GUID of your Tenant>";

private static async Task<SecurityToken> validateJwtTokenAsync(string token)
{
    // Build URL based on your AAD-TenantId
    var stsDiscoveryEndpoint = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{0}/.well-known/openid-configuration", TENANT);

    // Get tenant information that's used to validate incoming jwt tokens
    var configManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(stsDiscoveryEndpoint);

    // Get Config from AAD:
    var config = await configManager.GetConfigurationAsync();

    // Validate token:
    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidAudience = AUDIENCE,
        ValidIssuer = config.Issuer,
        IssuerSigningTokens = config.SigningTokens,
        CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.ChainTrust,
    };

    var validatedToken = (SecurityToken)new JwtSecurityToken();

    // Throws an Exception as the token is invalid (expired, invalid-formatted, etc.)
    tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out validatedToken);

    return validatedToken;
}
```

This only the raw Basics and was only tested using **net452**. Have a look at the link above for further usage (e.g. Caching the SigningTokens for a certain time).

Comment: I am getting Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.DateTimeUtil' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.0.0.127, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. when run the above code

Comment: Which framework did you use? This example code was only tested using net452. I will add a note in my post.

Comment: Where can I get config.Issuer & config.SigningTokens?